# Data for the City State and Countries of whole world in CSV data

Tags: database, mongodb, data-warehouse, huge-pages

stack overflow users,
I need huge data for my website which required city-state and country with pin codes will be utilized in the dropdown.
Please share the source if anyone has an idea, paid also will be okay for my requirement.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: No idea what you are looking for but have a look at https://ourworldindata.org/ or google for "opendata" (e.g. https://data.nasa.gov/)

Comment: I am seeking master data for the current Countries' States and City names.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out [Simplemaps.com](https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities) for city/state/country data.
   They have 3 tiers: Basic (free), Pro and Comprehensive (both paid). Check which one suits your needs.
2. Check out [this repository by dr5hn](https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database)

I'm not sure what you mean by *pin codes* in:

> with pin codes will be utilized in the dropdown.

but:

3. Check out the [All Postal Code - All countries (Geonames)](https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/geonames-postal-code%40public/information/) database by OpenData Soft

Answer (score 1):

I personal use this huge data in my projects, and this is continuosly updating by someone

[regions-countries-states-cities](https://github.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database/tree/master/csv)

you can find the other formats here like json, but json sometimes is quite bulky and takes time to read for my code

you can go back and check this repo